# ArrayType in WSDL

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wsdl, wsimport

having an error while executing wsimport. I am followint the link http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Web-Services-WSDL-Array-Array-Type-P517.html about transmit array type. What could be the problem?

```
[ERROR] undefined attribute 'soapenc:arrayType'
```

**XSD File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsd:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://com.company.hplistener.service/"
    xmlns:tns="http://com.company.hplistener.service/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/encoding/"     
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    >

    <xsd:complexType name="PrinterInsertInfo">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="percLevelBlack"  type="xsd:long" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="percLevelCyan"  type="xsd:long" />
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="percLevelYellow"  type="xsd:long" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>


        <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfPrinterInsertInfo">  
        <xsd:complexContent>   
            <xsd:restriction base="tns:PrinterInsertInfo">  
                <xsd:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:PrinterInsertInfo[]"/>  
            </xsd:restriction>  
        </xsd:complexContent>  
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: `arrayType` is defined in _http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/_ and not in _http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/encoding_. Try using `wsdl:arrayType` instead of 'soapenc:arrayType'.

Comment: tried it but having an error : [ERROR] undefined attribute 'wsdl:arrayType'

Comment: Can you please try after removing the `standalone="yes"` from prologue?

Comment: removed  standalone="yes" but having same issue.

Comment: Unless you tell me what issues, people out here won't be able to help.

Comment: Issue is having the error [ERROR] undefined attribute 'wsdl:arrayType'. Therefore Java class files is not created from wsdl/xsd